# Drawing multiple bitmaps on one Device Context in MFC - winapi

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I want to use a single `CDC`, inwhich to draw 3 bitmaps, positioned in the `CDC`, and then pass it into `UpdateLayeredWindow`. My problem is that I can't get the `SIZE* psize` parameter of the UpdateLayeredWindow function right! Can Anyone help? What do I do?

```
BLENDFUNCTION bBlendFnc = {
    AC_SRC_OVER,
    0,
    255,
    AC_SRC_ALPHA
};

CBitmap btCdcBuff;
CBitmap* cache;
BITMAP hbCdcBuff;

btCdcBuff.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pCdcMain, szWndSize.cx, szWndSize.cy); btCdcBuff.GetBitmap(&hbCdcBuff);

cache = pCdcMain->SelectObject(&btCdcBuff); // pCdcMain is a compatible CDC with the screen (pCdcScreen)

Blend(&btIcon); // This function just creates a compatible CDC from a CPaintDC, selects the passed in CBitmap via SelectObject and AlphaBlends it to the pCdcMain.
pCdcMain->SelectObject(cache);

UpdateLayeredWindow(pCdcScreen, NULL, new CSize(hbCdcBuff.bmWidth, hbCdcBuff.bmHeight), pCdcMain, new CPoint(0, 0), 0, &bBlendFnc, ULW_ALPHA) // This fails and returns false
```

Comment: What `psize` parameter to what function? Show us a minimal piece of code that still demonstrates the problem, and point out the exact part of it you're having trouble with, and we'll be in a much better position to help out.

Comment: There's a bit of example code which demonstrates what Im trying to do here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using CreateCompatibleBitmap with UpdateLayeredWindow, make sure you pass in the CDC for the screen (ie, pCdcScreen not pCdcMain), so that the Bitmap created is of the correct format. See this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsuidevelopment/thread/1fbcf5e4-b9eb-4537-bf0b-d330aa333fea